# how to display the thumbnail image

Tags: ios

How to display the Thumbnail image  for the video before playing. This is Simple question ,I am new in this field can any one help me to solve this problem

```
NSString *str11 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1"];  

NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:str11];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url1] ;
                [player play];

AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url1];

AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];

CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 1);
CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
NSLog(@"thumbmail %@",thumbnail);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no requirement to use MPMoviewPlayer then you can use UIWebView. There you will have preview thumbnail loaded automatically.

```
 [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1"]]];
```

[image]